# How to get past errors using putParameter with aws-sdk for nodejs in Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-ssm

I'm trying to set a parameter using putParameter in the [AWS SDK for JavaScript in Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SSM.html#putParameter-property).  In particular, I'd like to take advantage of the "Advanced" Tier, with an Expiration policy and Tags if possible.  When I execute my code, I keep getting errors like:

```
There were 2 validation errors:
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Policies' found in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Tier' found in params
```

I suspected the issue was around the aws-sdk version I was using, so I've tried running the code locally using [SAM local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-start-lambda.html), and from Lambda functions using the nodejs8.10 and nodejs10.x environments.  The errors do not go away.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
const ssm = new AWS.SSM({apiVersion: '2014-11-06'});

exports.lambdaHandler = async () => {

    const tokenExpiration = new Date();
    tokenExpiration.setSeconds(tokenExpiration.getSeconds() + 60);

    await ssm.putParameter({
        Name: 'SECRET_TOKEN',
        Type: 'SecureString',
        Value: '12345',
        Policies: JSON.stringify([
            {
               "Type":"Expiration",
               "Version":"1.0",
               "Attributes":{
                  "Timestamp": tokenExpiration.toISOString()
               }
            }
        ]),
        Overwrite: true,
        Tier: 'Advanced'
    }).promise();
};
```

I would expect this code to work and set a parameter with the expiration.  However, it appears that the sdk doesn't recognize the "Policies" and "Tier" parameters, which are available according to the documentation.  I don't know if it's an issue of waiting for the newest AWS SDK for JavaScript, but the [runtimes page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) suggest that nodejs10.x is running AWS SDK for JavaScript 2.437.0.

It might be helpful to know that I can get the code running correctly without the parameters in question (ie, just the "Name", "Type", and "Value" parameters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately both Tier and Policies weren't added until `v2.442.0` ([see diff](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/commit/e6e000319e42979d4a63ac7059e6ab95cd0ead72#diff-accc0b2b7abb2d6734ab2c89bdd855fcR10638))

This means that to use these features you'll have to deploy with the version of the `aws-sdk` you're developing against.

It should be noted that either developing/testing against the built-in version, or deploying with the `aws-sdk` you do use, is often cited as good practice. If you're deploying your version you can use explicit client imports (e.g. `const SSM = require('aws-sdk/clients/ssm')` to keep the deployment size down. This is even more effective if you develop against the preview [AWS-SDK Version 3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/new-aws-sdk-for-javascript-developer-preview/).

Comment: I would imagine that the build-in lambda sdk will be updated sooner or later, so this will probably solve itself then even if I don't take any action.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Once again the bearer of bad news, but the built-in aws-sdk only changes with each new runtime (as it is _potentially_ a breaking change for every deployed lambda), so I expect you won't get a higher version until the node 12 runtime is released.

Comment: It might be bad news, but it still saves me a lot of hassle.  Thanks again